# Issue with an appended element following characteristics of different element

Tags: javascript

The below code generates several elements with links and buttons; even when I am using a different link i.e. `game.website` for `gameAtt` and `/game.keyword.html` for `gameEl`, `gameAtt` does not follow `game.website` but follows the link I provide for `gameEl`. Why so and how can I make them work to open different websites?

```
filteredGames.forEach(function (game){

    const anchor  = document.createElement('div')
    const gameEl  = document.createElement('a')
    const gameAtt = document.createElement('button')

    gameEl.setAttribute('href', `/${game.keyword}.html`)
    gameAtt.textContent = 'Official Website'
    gameEl.textContent  = game.name

    anchor.appendChild(gameEl)
    gameEl.appendChild(gameAtt)
    gameAtt.setAttribute('href', `${game.website}`)
    document.querySelector('#games-list').appendChild(anchor)
})
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dkeu-D04zmdh2umzv-nBZjwKa86c0EKN) are all the files of the project.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a description of the desired/expected behaviour *before* describing the actual/problematic one. Describe it after the short intro sentence that I've added for you. Also I suggest you to describe the actual state in more detail: currently you only tell us what the actual behaviour is, but what about using DOM inspector and showing hrefs that the generated elements have? Finally, do your best to make reproducing your problem as easy as possible: obviously, your post doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve yet. Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have interactive content (`button`) within an [`a` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-a-element), it's not allowed per specification:

> **The `a` element**
>
> ...
>
> **Content model:**
>
> [Transparent](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#transparent), but there must be no [interactive content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#interactive-content-2) or a element descendants.

Also, [`button` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-button-element) don't have an `href` attribute, so it's not surprising that the one on the link (the `a` element) is the one that's being used.

Comment: So how do i correct this? I'm gonna try to use click event listeners for the button then, and see if that works for me. Any suggestions? Please let me know.

Comment: @RohanJangotra - The first thing you do is move the button out of the link, since again, it's invalid for it to be there, which means you have no guarantees about what browsers will do -- they might put the link and button next to each other, or put the link *in* the button, or... Then, yes, you could have a click handler on the button to do whatever you want the button to do, or put it in a `form` element with an `action` attribute (since the default `type` of `button` is `"submit"`, clicking the button would submit the form). It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: well i managed to get it to work as i wanted the same day i read this and got to know that buttons doesn't have href attribute. so what i did, is instead of appending button to the game name element i appendid it to the anchor element. secondly i used click event listener and added a function to open window.open(myurl) and this did just the action i wanted.

thank you so much for your help :)